# How can I recover the undo/redo buffer after automatic file formatting on save in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, undo-redo

1. Start with a file with invalid formatting, in a syntax for which you've configured Format on Save
2. Make some changes
3. `Undo` some of those changes
4. Save the file
5. Observe that the formatting problems have been automatically fixed
6. Attempt and fail to `redo` your `undo`ne changes

Is there any way to recover that redo buffer and those changes?

Comment: by formatting you replace the top of the undo stack, you add a new edit/undo point, it is the same as if you type some words, you then also loose the redo stack

Comment: I program for years and have never used/needed formatters, I don't type messy code, learn to do that and your live will be easy. Get used to use Python, a formatter will not work because that will ruin the meaning of the code.

Comment: in which editor do you have this functionality, I have used of lot of them and none have it, not even emacs